# Run sql script from file in PSQL and save output to file

Tags: psql

I have a large SQL script saved in a .sql format. I want to run it in PSQL on linux and then save the output to the file. In pgadmin it works just fine and I can see the output in the "messages" tab.

How can I do the same using psql?

This is the command I am running:

```
psql -h 192.168.0.150 -d database -U postgres -p 5432 -q -f /home/michal/Downloads/move_template_data.sql \o ~/Downloads/2020-10-09.txt
```

It executes, but nothing happens, no file is created.

Comment: The `\o ...` should be part of the SQL script

Comment: so can I do it in some other way? or add \o to the first line of the script?